# Sitecore Webforms for Marketers - one form, multiple screens

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, web-forms-for-marketers

Is it feasible to have a form in WFFM that has multiple "screens"? For instance in the first "screen" you enter some information and click NEXT, then the second "screen" asks you to confirm the information you entered in the first screen, and then the user clicks SUBMIT and the action (i.e. saving to DB) is performed.

Thanks,

FG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of functionality is not supported out of the box. Whenever we run into cases like this we tend to build our own custom forms using standard .net functionality. I guess this would be the way to go for you aswell, since you will have more control over the behavior of different elements. WFFM is a good module but for special elements as you describe above you could best build your own custom code.

Comment: The thing is that we already have a custom .NET form, but the client would like to switch to WFFM to have more flexibility and control in changing the layout of the form

Comment: You could offer him to switch to the WFFM giving more flexibility (he can add fields and change names etc.) but on the other side offering less functionality.

Comment: Yep, I am proposing a one page form with a different layout as a option. I was hoping there was a way to add this functionality to WFFM without too much effort.